# Changing Column Name in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rename

df.groupBy("state").sum("salary").show()
results in

state |sum(salary)
+-----+-----------+
|   NJ|      91000|
|   NV|     166000|
|   CA|     171000|
|   DE|      99000|
|   NY|     252000|

How can I do if I want to change "state" column name to "country" ?

Answer (score 0):

To definitely change the column's name:

```py
df = df.withColumnRenamed('state', 'country')
```

To display a different name in your query result:

```py
df = groupBy(df.state.alias("country")).sum("salary").show()
```